# How to rename files without extension

Tags: files, rename

I've a bunch of files that should be renamed programatically in order to be comprehensible by the application.

They have this formatting :
[image: Files to be renamed]

I need to cut from the end until the first _ and replace it by a dot(.).

As I don't know per advance the length of the filename neither the numbers of _ in the filename, do you have any idea trough awk/sed/cut ?

Comment: You should add some expected input and desired output.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for F in *_*; do echo mv -- "${F}" "${F%_*}.${F##*_}"; done
```

If the output looks correct then remove the `echo` command from above.

The trick is that `${F%_*}` removes last `_26` and `${F##*_}` removes everything before the last `_`. Try these commands to see how it works. The delimiter is now `:`:

```
echo "${PATH}"
echo "${PATH%:*}"
echo "${PATH##*:}"
echo "${PATH%:*}_${PATH##*:}"
```

Comment: you add `<!-- language: lang-none -->` before your codeblock to turn off syntax highlighting...

Comment: Hello hschou, Thanks it works like a charm !

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
for file in *_*
do 
    echo mv $file $( sed 's/\(.*\)_/\1\./' <<< $file)
done
```

Remove the `echo` if you're satisfied.

Comment: `sed` makes it slow. For each file you have to start a new process and that takes time. One should always try to use internal bash-commands.

Comment: @hschou I agree that the `bash` solution is the most efficient however he asked for solutions using `sed` or `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the last block with `sed`, using the end of line marker (`$`).

```
#/bin/bash
for file in *_* ; do
  #any alphanumeric string as suffix
  mv $file $( sed 's/_\([A-Za-z0-9]\{1,\}\)$/.\1/' <<< $file )
  #alternatively numbers only as in given input sample
  mv $file $( sed 's/_\([0-9]\{1,\}\)$/.\1/' <<< $file )
done
```

AFAIK the `\{1,\}` bit as "one or more" of the preceding list is GNU `sed` - but I'm not 100% sure of this restriction.